# I have problems running flask. Period

Tags: python, html, flask, jss

I already would like to apologize for my stupidity but I just cannot seem to get this to work and would greatly appreciate your help.

I have recently started to program (beyond novice). I want to create a JSS application and run it on a development server run by flask. I have installed flask, python and all necessary application (so far so good). My project directory looks like this:

[image of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw5ru.png)

my app.py looks like this:

```
`import os

import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

from helpers import usd

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='Users/bilob/Programming/FinalProject/templates')

app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

@app.route('/register', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    return render_template("register.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Installed routes:')
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
        print(f'{rule}: {rule.endpoint}')
    app.run(debug=True)`
```

Now, when I run "python app.py" in the Terminal, nothing happens. "pip show flask" let's me know that it can find flask and everything should be dandy. But everything is precisely not dandy.

Please help, I know there is not a lot of information but flask has been giving me trouble for hours and I may need a troubleshoot.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Sandro

I tried EVERYTHING. I was only expecting flask to work and show up properly.

Comment: The top candidate for causing this is the import from `helpers`.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I deleted it but flask still won't open. But thank you anyway for trying to help and not immediately downvoting